# Is it posible to conditionally disable NSValueTransformer for NSManagedObject attribute?

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, nsvaluetransformer

Specifically, say I have an NSManagedObject with a "statusCode" attribute set to transformable, and a reversible value transformer subclass to covert from NSStrings to NSNumbers and vice versa. The idea is to use the value transformer so that I receive JSON and a string from a "status" key in the JSON automatically maps to an NSNumber that represents that status code in an NSManagedObject. Conversely if I were to upload the NSManagedObject to a server, at that point its status attribute would be transformed from an NSNumber to a string for the JSON.

So far so good. But, what if I also want to be able to get a simple int out of the NSManagedObjec's status property, so that I can AND it with enums in code? 
That is, I'd lie to cover 3 cases:

1. `myManagedObject.status = [JSONResponse valueForKey:@"status"]` (should use transformer to do NSString -> NSNumber)
2. `[JSONforUpload setValue:myManagedObject.status forKey:@"status"]` (should use transformer to do NSNumber->NSString)
3. From elsewhere in code, anything along the lines of: `if(myManagedObject.status & statusInProgress) ...` where statusInProgress is an enum.

I'm thinking I could temporarily disable the value transformer, however I have no idea if the NSManagedObject has a reference to it, or if I should disable it from the NSValueTransformer class, which apparently keeps a table of registered transformers?

I know that for the 3rd case I could just do `[myManagedObject.status intValue]` and then do the bitwise comparison, but I'm wondering if there's any way I can have the `intValue]` be returned automagically, from the user of this object's point of view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to add a property to the transformer so that it switches between string and enum reversed values. That would work, though I ended up doing a enum<->string transformer and not using it over a transformable attribute (instead I left the managed object's attribute as int) but rather instantiating it only for the JSON <-> object conversion. After that, throughout code I just use the int attribute as is.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write two additional methods for the JSON transform and leave the property as integer? Then you'd have the best from both worlds.

Comment: that was my first approach and yes, it works. and I might just revert back to that if not. But I'm wondering if there's a way to pull it off and keep the transformable property.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this entity has its own distinct managed object subclass, you could also simply add another pair of accessor methods to the class to encapsulate the conversion between `NSNumber` and `int` values. (Or add a transient attribute, if it needs to be part of the model. But you'd still need to write custom accessors to synch up the values.)